# Sending SMS messages via a URL using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, url

I want to send an SMS message to many people.  I have the person type and phone number for each person in a MySQL table.  Using a stored procedure, I am calling a stored procedure in the database to get a list of phone numbers for all the people of a particular type and store it in a `DataTable` object.  I have one URL that I need to use to send all the messages for all the people of that same type.  The variable `s` in the below code is the person type which comes from a drop-down control:

```
Dim ta As New dataset1TableAdapters.pro_selectsmsTableAdapter
Dim dt As dataset1.pro_selectsmsDataTable = ta.GetData(s)
```

How do I loop through the resulting `DataTable` and send the SMS message to each one using the URL?  The variable `dt` has the list of phone numbers for the people who match the type stored in `s`.  Please help me solve this problem.  I am new to VB.NET.

Comment: What are the column names in the `dataset1.pro_selectsmsDataTable`?  What is the format of the URL?

Comment: datatable contains the column like fld_type,fld_phone,Fld_msg,Fld_status.the format of url is confidential. sorry am not able to give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?

```
Private Sub sendSmsMessage(ByVal message As String, ByVal s As String)
    Dim ta As New dataset1TableAdapters.pro_selectsmsTableAdapter
    Dim dt As dataset1TableAdapters.pro_selectsmsDataTable = ta.GetData(s)
    For Each dr As DataSet1.pro_selectsmsRow In dt
        Dim client As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(getSmsUrl("", "")) 'dr.fld_phone, message))
        Dim response As System.Net.WebResponse = client.GetResponse()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim responseText As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        ' look at response text from website to see if operation succeeded
    Next
End Sub

Private Function getSmsUrl(ByVal phone As String, ByVal message As String) As String
    ' build proprietary url and return it here
End Function
```